# +Ajax update page without reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, refresh

when I logged into system, it will display the book I has, when I clicked on the link books it will sort the book ascending if they are descending without refresh the page ,and if I clicked again it will sort them descending also without refresh the page,,, in my code when I clicked on the link he didn't do thing ,, i open inspect element he pass order_by_value:    DESC when i clicked again he pass in parameter order_by_value:ASC but he didn't do action why?

this function getBook in UUser.php

```
 public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2, $order = "ASC")
  {
   $sql_start = $start * $limit;
   $sql_limit = $limit;
   $sql_order_by = $order;

   $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username ORDER BY Library.nameOfBook $sql_order_by LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
   $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
   $statment->execute([
       ':username' => $this->username
   ]);
   $result = $statment->fetchAll();

  echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'>

  <tr>
   <th><a id='sorter' href='#'>Books</a></th>
   <th>Action</th>
   </tr>";
   foreach($result as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
   echo "";
   return count($result);
 }
```

this is my ajax in index.php

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#sorter").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var order_by_value = $('input[name="order_by"]').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
       url: "" + 'UUser.php',
      data: {
     'order_by_value': order_by_value,
     // button: 'button',
      },
      success: function (res) {
        if(order_by_value == "ASC"){
       $('input[name="order_by"]').val("DESC");
      }
      else {
       $('input[name="order_by"]').val("ASC");
       }
   // $('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');
    }
   });
});
});
```

this script in index.php to next and prev the table

```
<?php
 $start = intval(isset($_POST['start'])?$_POST['start']:0);
 $order_by_hidden = isset($_POST['order_by'])?$_POST['order_by']:"ASC";
 if(isset($_POST['previous'])){
   $start = $start -1;
   //if($start < 1) $start = 1;
    $start= max($start, 1);
}
else if(isset($_POST['current'])){
    $start = $start;
}
else if(isset($_POST['next'])){
   $start = $start + 1;
}
else {
$start = 1;
}
?>
```

this is my form also in index.php

```
 <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
 Name: <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $user;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $password;?>" >
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
<br><br>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $start;?>" name="start"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order_by_hidden;?>" name="order_by"/>
 <button type="button" name="button" onclick="window.location.href='/ooRigester.php'">SignUp</button>
  <br><br>
  <input type='submit' name='previous' value='previous' <?php echo ($start <= 1 ? "disabled" : ""); ?>>
 <input type='submit' name='next' value='next'><br>
 <input type='button' name='current' value='current' style="display:none;"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#sorter").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: @mplungjan no its not dublicate ... whats your problem ????

Comment: 1. You had the exact same question. 2. The answer to both questions are "Add preventDefault to the link click - Please try it. - You likely want to echo the start value in the PHP

Comment: i added and still refresh the page why sir ?

Comment: Because you are triggering `$('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');` it will ALSO reload the page if you do not preventDefault and ajax the values

Comment: so how i can fix this problem ? @mplungjan

Comment: You need to ajax everything and change the submit buttons to type="button"

Comment: i change the current to button ... you mean that right ?

Comment: @mplungjan i update my code plz check it ,,, i change submit current to button and i passed in data ajax ,,, now he stop refresh but he didn't do sort ,,, i check the param in incpect element he just send ASC an button current,,, how i can change the asc to desc when i clicked on the link ?

Comment: Use https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ - I suggest you have ONE PHP return results and have the same function for all buttons and make all buttons type="button" class="button" - then you can use: `$(".button").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var whichButton = this.name, $form = $("#form1");$("name="+whichButton+"_hidden]").val(this.value);$.ajax({url:$form.attr("action"), data:$form.serialize(),success:....}); });`

Comment: and where i pass id of the link ?

Comment: if you can plz write your answer down

Comment: You pass the values in the hidden fields. You already do that